# Multiple rows update in one statement with Knex

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, node-postgres

I trying to update multiple rows in one statement with following syntax:

```
update test as t set
    column_a = c.column_a,
    column_c = c.column_c
from (values
    ('123', 1, '---'),
    ('345', 2, '+++')  
) as c(column_b, column_a, column_c) 
where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

How can I do it with Knex? Or only one way is to use pg-node prepared statements?

Comment: Did you try knex transaction?

Comment: @mdmundo, transactions is committed one by one, right? If the statement is prepared as one bulk it supposed to be faster, no?

Answer (score 0):

AFAK knex doesn't have any tools to help with this kind of query. Though you can do it by using `knex.raw()`.